# how to save data using one to one mapping in jpa and hibernate when primary key was assigne manully

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I am trying to save data into two tables which contains same primary key in two tables which was assgned manually.
Below is the code what i wrote

This is simple code not actual code ,original code well and good formatted.

```
@Entity 
@TABLE(bookDetails)
  class Book{
    @Id private Long bookId; // in mycase it is not generated value it assigned programtically
    private String name;
    @OnetoOne 
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private BookOtherDetails bookOtherInfo;
  // more code  
}   

@Entity
@Table(bookOhterDetails)  
class BookOtherDetails{
    @Id
    private Long bookId;// same as bookId in Book
    private String authorName;
   // more details   
}
```

But the problem i am not able insert data in bookOtherDetails table.Please guideme if i did any thing wrong.

Thanks in future.

Comment: There's a typo in the `@Table` annotation of the second entity. "bookOhterDetails" instead of "bookOtherDetails". In fact, there are several more typos in your code. I do not believe this even compiles. What error message do you get?

Answer (score 0):

You've got a property on Book which is of type BookOtherDetails. The class you've supplied as the OneToOne is of type BookOtherInfo.

I think you need to change the type of the reference on Book to be a BookOtherInfo.

Comment: I changed original post.still not working for me.Thanks for reply

Comment: Also can you post any stack traces or other errors encountered on save.

Comment: I saw one related topic asked some one in same forum.Some one replies that onetoone annotation with  primarykey annotation has some problem in jpa.

Comment: Edit your original question to include the additional details.